# Remainder of a complex function

Tags: complex-numbers, divisibility

Dividing $f(z)$ by $z-i$, the remainder is $1-i$ and by dividing $z+i$ the remainder is $1+i$, then what is the remainder when $f(z)$ is divided by $z^2+1$?

I just started solution using division algorithm, but I struck at beginning. I am not getting any idea. Please give some hints. I'll try.

Give me the solution/hint.

Comment: In your problem, the function f(z) is f(z)=z^4 - iz   Does that help?

Comment: Ok, I ll try, But how can you say its $z^4-iz$?

Comment: I am not saying that my function is THE function. However, it is a function that matches your remainders.

Comment: I am getting different remainders when dividing $z^4-iz$ by $z-1$ and $z+i$.

Comment: I was thinking about the Rational Zero Theorem. Apperantly that does not work for complex terms. In fact, z^4 - iz is perfectly divisible by z-1 ! But putting z=1 in z^4-iz does not give zero. Clearly something is wrong here...

Comment: Did you mean $\,z-\color{#c00}1\,$ or $\,z-\color{#c00}i\,?$ It's highly likely that the former is a typo for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $z^2+1=(z-i)(z+i),$ the first divisor should be $z-i$

If $f(z)=(z-i)(z+i)g(z)+A(z-i)+B(z+i)$ where $g(z)$ is another polynomial

So,  $f(i)=2iB$ and $f(-i)=-2iA$

and using [Polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem),  $f(i)=1-i$  and $f(-i)=1+i$

Comparing the values of $f(i), 2iB=1-i, B=\frac{1-i}{2i}=-\frac{1+i}2$

Similarly, compare values of $f(-i),$ to get the value of $A$

Now, $$f(z)=(z-i)(z+i)g(z)+A(z-i)+B(z+i)=(z^2+1)g(z)+z(A+B)+i(B-A)$$

Can you identify the remainder?

Comment: Ok, But how to get remainder? dividing $f(z)$ by $z^2+1$?

Comment: @SHREE6174, please find the edited version

Comment: I am not getting.. I understood the above, but I am not getting remainder. The options are  <br/>
(a)$i+z$  <br/>
(b)$1-z$  <br/>
(c)$1+z$  <br/>
(d)$i(1+z)$  <br/>

Comment: @SHREE6174, clearly it should be $1+z$

Comment: Thank you very much @lab bhattacharjee. You helped me a lot. I understood new concept here. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, here Problem is, dividing $f(z)$ by $z-1$ remainder is $1-i$. Not $z-i$
How you get $f(i)=1-i$?

Comment: @SHREE6174, please read the first line of the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9098/discussion-between-shree6174-and-lab-bhattacharjee)

Comment: Yes, I got $1-z$. The first divisor should be $z-i$.

Comment: @SHREE6174 It can be solved more simply, since the problem has been constructed to make the remainder *obvious* - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}  f(z) &=& (z^2+1)q(z)\ +\ r(z)\\ &=& (z\!-\!i)(z\!+\!i)q(z) + r(z)\end{eqnarray}\!\bigg\rbrace$ $\Rightarrow\left[\begin{eqnarray} r(i) &=& f(i) &=& 1\!-\!i\\ r(-i) &=& f(-i) &=& 1\!+\!i\end{eqnarray}\right].\,$ Clearly $\,r(z) = 1\!-\!z\,$ works.

No other linear polynomial $\,r'\,$ works, otherwise $\,r-r'\ne 0\,$ has deg $< 2\,$ but has $\,2\,$ roots $\,\pm i.$

Comment: I cleared. But, Is there any possible to find reminder for the same question if first divisor is $z-1$?